# using memcached with Doctrine in Symfony4 application

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, memcached, php-7, symfony4

I am working on a project and I need to use memcached features to cache the queries and results.

I have followed the tutorial from [this](https://medium.com/@stefan.poeltl/symfony-and-memcached-the-ultimate-guide-for-a-high-performance-setup-854eaf77eb3b).

Do I need to use below code for each query?

> ->useQueryCache(true)
>
> ->useResultCache(true, 3600)

Is there any alternative like to setup somewhere in `services` file or `config` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`DoctrineBundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-bundle) in your Symfony application - then you can, of course, configure Memcached cache use for Doctrine through [configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#caching-drivers).

Comment: Sorry. I am already using that configuration. But it did not work.